# Installing debian packages in Yocto with a recipe

Tags: linux, debian, yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I am making an operating system with Yocto. I created new meta, new layer, new recipe and new machine. It was working fine until I tried to include packages already compiled for debian. Normally, I was installing these packages with the apt-get command after flashing the image, but as the number of packages increased, they started to conflict with the packages that came with the image and compiled with bitbake, so I am trying to add these packages as a recipe.

Can I create recipe directly from .deb file or .dsc file? If I can't create it, how can I find the source code and how can I create a recipe from the source code?

I'm currently using the OpenEmbedded dunfell version, but I'm planning to switch to the kirkstone version. Since I'm using dunfell version, I'm looking at debian's stretch version packages. Which version packages of debian should I look for when I switch to kirkstone version?

I am compiling for armhf architecture on Intel 64 bit Ubuntu 18.04. I'm compiling for a custom board.

These are the packages I'm trying to install for now (I think I can install similar packages if I can install them with a recipe):

1. [xbindkeys](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/xbindkeys)
2. [libcrypto++6](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcrypto++6)
3. [libcurl3-gnutls](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcurl3-gnutls)
4. [default-jre-headless](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/default-jre-headless)
5. [libccid](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libccid)
6. [libpam-pkcs11](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libpam-pkcs11)
7. [pcscd](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pcscd)
8. [libacsccid1 (This is special because it only has deb package. There is no source code or dsc file.)](https://dosya.co/j9plnrbhf55y/libacsccid1_1.1.8-1%7Ebpo9+1_armhf.deb.html)

Answer (score 3):

Whilst Yocto Project and OpenEmbedded can output deb packages they are only compatible with the DISTRO setting that built them in OE. Packages from Debian are not compatible.

You can look at https://layers.yoctoproject.org/ to search for recipes in other layers which may be able to build what you need once those layers are added.

Where you can't build from source you may be able to extract files from a Debian deb and turn it into a different deb that might work with OE but it assumes the binaries are compatible and they may or may not be depending on how you've configured your build. This isn't recommended.

Comment: Among the layers, these packages I mentioned either do not exist or do not work properly like these ready-made debs (maybe because of the version difference.). How do you open the deb package, which is the second method you mentioned, and compile it again? These deb packages are suitable for armhf, that is, for my target board, but I need to compile them on intel 64. How can I do it?